# JSF component to display a timetable/calendar/agenda

Tags: java, jsf, calendar, primefaces, timetable

Is there a JSF/PrimeFaces component to implement a timetable/agenda/calendar? It should display a table with the days of the week and the hours of the day. That means a total of 168 squares that can be selected by the user.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf <-- What about this? (Switch to 'week')

Comment: Looks like a good solution for my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf

You *could* check out the tomahawk project as well, it comes with such a component to. But as you seemingly are already using primefaces . . . anyway http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html

Edit: I used to be a myfaces/tomahawk user (and used their schedule comp, but back in jsf 1.1 days :). One day I switched to the jsf (2.0) implementation provided as part of the glassfish project and primefaces. From there I never looked back, but ymmv.